# Enforce URL rules when posting content types

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri

so I created a content type "Regions" - This includes the 13 provinces in Canada listed as individual terms.

When creating a new post with the content type "Regions", you have to choose which term to post into. Let's say I would like to post a page "TEST POST ONTARIO", I post it in the term "Ontario"

I would like the URL from this post to be automatically changed to
www.website.com/region/on/testpost
by default, it posts to www.website.com/testpost

Is there a way to automate the url for when this content type is created? or would you have to manually change the url alias every post?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.  This lets you create default patterns on a per content type basis that can use information from fields on the node to create a URL.